# "What a good boy I am!" vs. "What a good boy am I!"

Tags: word-order, clauses

What is the difference between "What a good boy **I am!"** and "What a good boy **am I!"**?

These two exclamative sentences are different in the matter of Subject-auxiliary inversion.

What I want to know is the subtle meaning or pragmatic difference the two sentences bring to native speakers.

Comment: It's a sentence and not a question. And thus, *"....I am."*

Comment: @MaulikV - _What a good boy am I_ is a line from a [famous nursery rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Jack_Horner). (Of course, if Line 3 read "Eating his Christmas *jam*," this wouldn't be an issue.)

Comment: Rhyme and meter. Such a funny thing.  From whence cometh words such as completer, in order a pretty song to... giraffe.

Answer (score 1):

When you're exclaiming a fact (in surprise), you are not asking a question. As such, we always use "sentence order"; that is: subject > verb.

> What a good boy I am!
>
> What a wonderful day it is!
>
> How nice you are!

I have not been able to think of a single situation where we could ask a question using this "What a/an + noun phrase" or "How + adjective" style (though if someone were to come up with such an example, then I suppose question order (verb > subject) would be applied).